# How to include the expression and unicode in a label in R?

Tags: r, unicode, label

I don't find a way to show an expression and the "per-mille" symbol in the same label. I have tried the next four ways:

```
name1 <- paste(expression(delta^18*O),"(\u{2030})")
name2 <- "\u{1E9F}O18 (\u{2030})"
name3 <- expression(delta^18*O)
name4 <- expression(paste(delta^18*O,"(\u{2030})"))
```

All of them show errors,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this it?

```r
name3 <- expression(delta^18 * O * "(\u{2030})")
plot(1, xlab = name3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

For more space between elements, use tildes instead of asterisks.

```
name3 <- expression(delta^18 ~ O ~ "(\u{2030})")
name3 <- expression(delta^18 * O ~ "(\u{2030})")
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want. I tried it, but it shows like the 4 option, it may be a locale problem?

Comment: @maggi Run `capabilities()` and see what the devices results are. It seems more like a device or an encoding problem. Do you have fonts where the per mille symbol can be found installed?

Comment: @HateSpinach See if [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/05/unicode-symbols-in-r/) can help.

Comment: Thank you! I looked it up, it wasn't set in UTF-8.

Comment: @HateSpinach, I'd guess you're on Windows, but not using R 4.2.0.  If that's the case, then you should update.